Calling the Win32_Service class is VERY slow
I have some servers where I experience a very slow response when calling the Win32_Service through Get-WmiObject/Get-CimInstance. It takes anywhere between 20-45 minutes when calling the Win32_Service class this way. If I use "Get-Service", it returns instantly and the servers are running fine in production, other than this issue.
All servers where I experience this issue are physical and running Server Core. They are all running Exchange Server as well. No other servers in the domain have this issue, the rest of them are all virtual though, so it's hard to do a 1:1 comparison. But other servers with the same OS, in same OU doesn't have this issue.
Have anybody seen a similar issue or have a great idea where to look for the root problem?
Update: It's not the whole class that is causing issues, it's only when getting the status of the service it fails. Only getting the name of services works fine:
wmic path win32_service get name (takes <1 second)
wmic path win32_service get status (takes +20 minutes)

Try testing with an equivalent WMIC command, and local vs remote.

wmic service get take +20 minutes as well. Using Get-CimInstance remote takes a long time as well.

I was finally able to solve this issue. The issue was caused by the Elastic Metricbeat log shipper. As soon as I stopped the process, it started working again. A few seconds after starting the process, the issue re-occurred.
After updating to the latest 8.14.0 version it was solved. I don't see anything in the change log that matches the issue I've seen.
I was able to reproduce the issue on both physical machines and VMs. With both version 8.10.2 and 8.12.2.
The problem is resolved in 8.14.0.
